# What is the proper structure for inserting data based on this schema?

Tags: mysql, symfony

I have a table schema that looks like this:

```
mysql> desc category;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name        | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| create_date | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

I have tried to insert data and I continue to get this error:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO category (id, name, create_date) VALUES (NULL, Family Events, 2016-25-12 00:00:00), (NULL, Work Events, 2016-25-12 00:00:00);
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Events, 2016-25-12 00:00:00), (NULL, Work Events, 2016-25-12 00:00:00)' at line 1
```

I have tried several other ways with the same result and I haven't found any good documentation.

I tried this:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO category(id, name, create_date) VALUES(NULL, 'Family Events', 'NOW()');
```

and got this error:

```
ERROR 1292 (22007): Incorrect datetime value: 'NOW()' for column 'create_date' at row 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [OP agreed with my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41324396/what-is-the-proper-structure-for-inserting-data-based-on-this-schema#comment69852499_41324396), I am adding it. The problem with the procedure you follow is, you should surround your string values with `'`:

```
-- If the column is a `DATETIME`, then use:
VALUES (NULL, 'Family Events', NOW()),
//------------^-------------^
-- If the column is a `TIMESTAMP`, then use:
VALUES (NULL, 'Family Events', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),
//------------^-------------^
```

Also I am using `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` for the timestamp insertion alternatively to `NOW()`.

One more thing that others have pointed out is, you don't need to add the extra `id` in your `INSERT` as it automatically does it based on `PRIMARY KEY` and since it takes `NULL` values, you can get rid of it completely.

Your final SQL should look like:

```
INSERT INTO category(name, create_date) VALUES('Family Events', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

Comment: the answer with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and of course the quotes was the solution.

Comment: @Daniel Thanks... I have added both the variations to it...

Comment: @Daniel Check that I have given the explanation for what to use when... `:)`